# DataTables 1.10: enable/disable colReorder by button

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I need to enable/disable colReorder for DataTables by clicking without reload page. I only found this solution:

```
$('#btn-table-edit').click(function() {
    var t = $('#table').DataTable();
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-pencil')) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-pencil').addClass('fa-check');
        new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder(t, {
            fixedColumnsLeft: 2,
            fixedColumnsRight: 2
        } );
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-pencil');
        t.destroy();
        $('#table').DataTable();
    }
});
```

But `destroy()` and after re-init table very heavy operation. Maybe is there better solution?

Comment: Did you try `$('#table').DataTable( { colReorder: true} );`?

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ: `Cannot reinitialise DataTable`